# SMS (MobileConnect) - Retrieving Additional Tracking Data

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect, sms

The Data Views made available to all customers with regards to SMS / MobileConnect are extremely lacking, and wouldn't allow one to pull in information relating to engagement activity.

As far as I'm aware we can only track opt ins: https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/data_view_subscribersms/

And undeliverables: https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/data_view_undeliverable_sms/

I've seen previous topics relating to this issue, but they just mention that it is possible to have custom reports created or made available by the SFMC services team. But I've never seen further discussion on what is possible to be included within those reports.

Obviously that is a discussion to have with the Services Team at SFMC, which I am going through now, but even then I am still receiving some conflicting information on what extent of information can be retrieved. I thought best to see if users have personal experience on what they were able to get delivered.

Main areas looking to track:

- SMS send
- SMS send date
- SMS open
- SMS open date
- SMS click
- SMS click date
- SMS link URL

Answer (score 1):

You can only track the delivery of a SMS. You can't get direct information regarding it's engagement back.

If you want information regarding clicks I'd suggest using a shortend URL with tracking.

What you can get out of MobileConnect is detailed here:

https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/mobile_messages/

To get what information is avaiable out of SFMC regarding your SMS's I'd suggest looking at either a API call or my preference using a query

https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/